# MatLab Coder - MatLab to C

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I am trying to run MatLab Coder to transform a matlab .m file into .mex to hopefully run the code more quickly.
When trying to build the file via MatLab Coder engine, I get the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'k'. The first assignment to a local variable determines its class.
```

k is determined inside a previous loop. My guess is that C code cannot "remember" values inside an earlier loop. How can I come around this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide fragment of you source file, where you got an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of "Undefined function or variable" errors were on variables, and all variables were 1 x 1 doubles, you have to just define them all as 0 prior to them being defined in a for loop. It seems you can not define them in a for loop.